# WCF Generic Dictionary and Understanding WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, generics, iis

Okay, I'm having a large amount of difficulty solving a particular issue. The transfer of an object through the service.  Conceptually, it makes sense... I think? From what I've read, a Generic can't be serialized unless it has been explicitly defined.

So I'd like to provide my example; in which I can't get to work at all. Which means; I'm sure there are others who experience some difficulty as well. When you assist if you could provide the code; that would work and explain it.  That way I can fully understand the issue.  Which will assist me on well, understanding the Windows Communication Foundation.

The goal is a client application which simply has five fields; in which it 'Post' to the server.

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email Address
- Phone Number
- Site Address

Which isn't too complicated.

Here is what I've done, which in my quest to learn WCF I've included as close to OOP Principals as I can for a SOA based application.  That way it provides code re-useability.

Model / Data Contract:

```
#region Using Reference...

using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System;

#endregion

namespace _2Do.Model.Customer
{

    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class Person
    {

        #region Declared Variable.

        string first;
        string last;
        string email;
        string phone;
        string site;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor:

        Person()
        {

            // Empty Constructor.

        }

        #endregion

        #region Data Member Properties:

        [DataMember()]
        public string First
        {

            get { return first; }
            set { first = value; }

        }

        [DataMember()]
        public string Last
        {

            get { return last; }
            set { last = value; }

        }

        [DataMember()]
        public string Email
        {

            get { return email; }
            set { email = value; }

        }

        [DataMember()]
        public string Phone
        {

            get { return phone; }
            set { phone = value; }

        }

        [DataMember()]
        public string Site
        {

            get { return site; }
            set { site = value; }

        }

        #endregion

    }

}
```

So that is the object in which should be exposed through the Metadata for the client; so for the Service interface I attempted this:

```
#region Using Reference...

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using _2Do.Model.Customer;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System;

#endregion

namespace _2Do.Contract.Customer
{

    [ServiceContract (Namespace = "https://_2Do") ]
    public interface IPerson
    {

        [OperationContract()]
        Person SetCustomer(Dictionary<Guid, Person> info);

    }

}
```

So the above is the goal; to transfer my Person object; stored into a Dictionary.  The other thing to note; is I thought the implementation of passing the values by reference would assist in the serialization.  I figured once the data is stored in memory; it would contain an explicit methodology for it to handle.  Is that wrong on my part?

So that is my `DataContract` and `ServiceContract`.

The implementation at this point is like this:

```
#region Using Reference...

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using _2Do.Contract.Customer;
using System.ServiceModel;
using _2Do.Model.Customer;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System;

#endregion

namespace _2Do.Service.Customer
{

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class PersonService : IPerson
    {

        #region Constructor:

        PersonService()
        {

            // Empty Constructor.

        }

        #endregion

        #region Implement Interface:

        Person SetCustomer(Dictionary<Guid, Person> info)
        {

            // Receive an error that indicates; best overload method.
            // Contains invalid arguments.

        }

        #endregion

    }

}
```

Then I created a separate project to host the application; which I created an empty text file and renamed it to `PersonService.svc`.

Which then I put: `<%@ ServiceHost Service = "_2Do.Service.Customer.PersonService" %>`.

Which should point to the proper namespace; which In the `PersonService` I have a `web.config` file that contains the bare minimum configuration to host in Internet Information System.  Which I thought would allow me to circumvent defining my Address, Binding, and Contract. As IIS will do it all for me now.

Then I've created a `ClientProxy` class; which contains a mirror almost of the `DataContract`. Then I've created the actual client application to do:

```
PersonProxy p = new PersonProxy();
p.First = txtFirst.Text;
p.Last = txtLast.Text;
p.Email = txtEmail.Text;
p.Phone = txtPhone.Text;
p.Site = txtSite.Text;
Dictionary<Guid, Person> i = new Dictionary<Guid, Person>();
i.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), p);
```

I've got these projects:

- Model --> DataContract
- Contract --> ServiceContract
- Service --> Implementation for Interfaces
- Host --> Stores Service / Svc
- ClientProxy --> Implementation for Interface
- Client --> Linked to actual values for ClientProxy to inherit.

Which is how I consume it on the Client.  I'm not sure where I've messed up this.  I'd really like to understand WCF as I need to learn it for a work project.  But I'm so frustrated and feel so stupid as I can't seem to solve this issue.

If I follow tutorials, it works.  But once I go back to my original implementation it fails.  Not sure what or where I'm going wrong.  Some hand holding would be appreciated; but if you could explain it step by step it'd be so appreciated. So I can learn from my mistakes to actually improve.

I can't get it to store the variable on the server, transmit, and I have no clue why at this point.

Comment: my current guess is that you haven't set up the Data Contract class correctly. I think you need another class that derives from `Dictionary` and has the `CollectionDataContract` attribute set.  I'm working on reproducing your code to check.

Comment: If you can get it to work I'll be the happiest person ever; I honestly can't get this stupid service working at all.  I appreciate your response and assistance.

Comment: strange, my code seems to work passing parameters as well as results. what version of the framework are you using?

Comment: one more (non-WCF) thing: make sure the `SetCustomer` method in the `PersonService` is marked `public`.

Comment: Framework 4.5 I wonder if it is because of my separation of Assemblies. Or if I screwed up Host / Client Proxy.

Comment: What did you do Vlad?  That is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure why your code is not working.  Perhaps I don't understand hosting in IIS as well as I should.  However, below is a fully working sample of the simplest web service + client that I can come up with.  Hopefully it will help you find and address the issue.

First of all, [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdpnm.jpg): contracts in one class library project, service and host in a console app, client in a different console app.

Data contract:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPerson
{
    [OperationContract]
    Person SetCustomer(Dictionary<Guid, Person> info);
}
```

Service:

```
public class PersonService : IPerson
{
    public Person SetCustomer(Dictionary<Guid, Person> info)
    {
        foreach (var person in info.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} | Email: {1}", person.Name, person.Email);
        }

        var p = new Person { Name = "John Doe", Email = "John@Doe.com" };
        return p;
    }
}
```

Service Host (in the host project's Program.cs):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(PersonService), new Uri("http://localhost:8080")))
    {
        host.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Ready!");
        Console.ReadKey(true);

        host.Close();
    }
}
```

And finally, client (in its own project's Program.cs):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8080/");
    using (var factory = new ChannelFactory<IPerson>(binding, endpoint))
    {
        var request = new Dictionary<Guid, Person>();
        request[Guid.NewGuid()] = new Person { Name = "Bob", Email = "Bob@abc.com" };

        var client = factory.CreateChannel();
        var result = client.SetCustomer(request);

        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} | Email: {1}", result.Name, result.Email);
        factory.Close();
    }
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In your example with the service; you add a new item.  I'm assuming that is coming from the server.  What if I wanted it reversed?  Where the client is actually feeding the variable for the server.  Where the business layer could write to database or write to a log.  Or just use those variables.

Comment: And that is a nice post, I'll def compare and review to see if I can figure it out and let you know.

Comment: @Greg my client creates a `Dictionary<Guid,Person>` and adds one element to it before sending it to the service.  I did that to test whether sending would work correctly.  Also, the service sends a different `Person` object back, which also works in my example.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a try and let you know.  Your post may solve my questions.

Comment: @Greg also check out msdn for how to host a WCF service in IIS. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx) If you still need help, I will try to get it working in IIS myself.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually looking at that MSDN article.  I'm going to try it as well.  I'd like to figure out why it isn't working for me.  Thanks again for assistance.

Comment: So it appears that the issue is indeed caused by the hosting; once I get it sorted out I'll post and mark.

Comment: Did you have any luck Vlad?  It appears to still be causing me problems with the abstraction.

Comment: Well, when I was following that MSDN it is assuming I used the 'template'.  Except I didn't want all those additional endpoints and not necessary items.  So I tried to abstract the assemblies into more manageable and reusable pieces. So I think my own assembly may have an issue.  At least in my case.

Comment: Your post answered my question; or at least exposed the real issue.  The hosting in IIS.  I tried the service with your method; of self hosting.  It appears to work.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to have a Dictionary as a parameter of your service contract? Keep it simple - use a List instead. My suggestion is:

1) Add the Guid property to the Person data contract

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Person
{
    #region Constructor:

    public Person()
    {
        // Empty Constructor.
    }

    #endregion

    #region Data Member Properties:

    [DataMember]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string First { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Last { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Site { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

2) Change the service contract to use a List:

```
[ServiceContract (Namespace = "https://_2Do") ]
public interface IPerson
{
    [OperationContract()]
    Person SetCustomer(List<Person> info);
}
```

3) The client code would be like this:

```
PersonProxy p = new PersonProxy();
p.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
p.First = txtFirst.Text;
p.Last = txtLast.Text;
p.Email = txtEmail.Text;
p.Phone = txtPhone.Text;
p.Site = txtSite.Text;

var list = new List<Person>();
list.Add(p);
```

Finally, if you really need a Dictionary in your service code you can easily convert the List using the method [ToDictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/todictionary)

Comment: Thanks for the post; I'll try that out.  See if my issue is in the Generic or if I screwed up the Client / Separation of Assemblies.